# Specify zero or one directory in path

Tags: regex, linux, wildcard

I'm trying to specify two possible paths in one path:

"username/public/tests/"
"username/tests/"

so in case if there is no 'public' directory, it simply omits it.

I tried the following "username/?(.|public)/tests", but it doesn't accept . as current path. Is there any other way to do it? I need to specify path this way in js configuration file, so I can't use bash scripting for it. Basically I need it to work with cd command. Thank you

Comment: The answer is going to depend on what's reading that js configuration file and whether it supports multiple choices. I'll be a bit surprised if regex is supported, but providing a list of paths to try may be (akin to Windows or Unix search paths).

Comment: JS reads LESS linter on Grunt, I need to be flexible with import paths, because their destinations change.